# Can't kill process in Heroku (dynos scaled to zero, ps empty, restart/stop claim success, output still continues)

Tags: heroku, kill, kill-process, heroku-toolbelt

### The problem

I can't seem to stop my application (node.js 0.10.12) to confirm that it's running my latest environment.

### Background

I have:

- Scaled all dynos to 0
- heroku ps reports no dynos/tasks/processes
- heroku restart claims to succeed
- heroku ps:stop claims to succeed

...yet output from my previous dyno continues. It looks like this:

```
2013-08-03T07:49:32.637139+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2013-08-03T07:49:32.659860+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=0 by heroku@circuithub.com
2013-08-03T07:49:32.732688+00:00 app[web.1]: error rabbitConnectedError RabbitMQ server at @lemur.cloudamqp.com/nfeqoqcg reports ERROR. { [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' } []
2013-08-03T07:49:34.315956+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-08-03T07:49:34.775579+00:00 app[web.1]: error rabbitConnectedError RabbitMQ server at @lemur.cloudamqp.com/nfeqoqcg reports ERROR. { [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' } []
2013-08-03T07:49:35.720788+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2013-08-03T07:49:36.743217+00:00 app[web.1]: error rabbitConnectedError RabbitMQ server at @lemur.cloudamqp.com/nfeqoqcg reports ERROR. { [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' } []
2013-08-03T07:49:38.797592+00:00 app[web.1]: error rabbitConnectedError RabbitMQ server at @lemur.cloudamqp.com/nfeqoqcg reports ERROR. { [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' } []
2013-08-03T07:49:40.787696+00:00 app[web.1]: error rabbitConnectedError RabbitMQ server at @lemur.cloudamqp.com/nfeqoqcg reports ERROR. { [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' } []
2013-08-03T07:49:42.812921+00:00 app[web.1]: error rabbit
ConnectedError RabbitMQ server at @lemur.cloudamqp.com/nfeqoqcg reports ERROR. { [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' } []
```

This output continues indefinitely (the node-amqp driver will endlessly attempt reconnection, by design) meaning the dyno is still running. It's still running now (about 2 hours later).

### The asks

1. Did I miss anything? Is there any way to actually shutdown a dyno formation?
2. There has to be something better (cheaper, more performant, more reliable) out there that allows git push?